# I cannot gain access to an internet connection

Tags: motorola-moto-g

I had to do a hard reset on my device!Now i cannot log into my google apps at the set up of my phone, nor can i get any internet connection. Can you help? Im not sure how to fix this problem.

Comment: Are you trying to use a mobile data connection or a WiFi connection?

Comment: ive tried both neither will alow me on

Comment: If you try to connect via WiFi, can you establish a connection to the network or does it fail immediately? Any error messages?

Comment: Can you please elaborate your issue... Please mention the device and ROM which you using.

Answer (score 0):

Verify the APN settings for your network operator. It may happen that an incorrect APN profile is selected which is prohibiting you from getting network access.

Comment: That cannot hurt – but wouldn't explain why it fails on WiFi as well.

Comment: Me? I'm not the OP. I guess you wanted to place this comment on the question itself, not on your answer :)